# Flask does not return db query when I use the JS hide/unhide. Works if I comment out JS

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to retrieve data from the database based on a users search results. The results, in a table format, should only be shown after the user hits the search button.

Query executes fine when javascript is cancelled out and the table "list" display is changed to block. However, when I enable the javascript I get no results.

```
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method=post  action="/">
            <dl style="display: inline-block; text:white;" >{{render_field(form.search)}}           </dl>
            <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="fetchlist(); return false;">Search</button>   
            <br>
            {% if error %}
            <p class = "error"><strong>Error:</strong>{{error}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        </form>


    </div>

            <div  style="text-align:center;">   
            <table id="list" style="display:none;" class = "table table-hover" >
            <thead>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Rating</th>
            <th scope="col">Review</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for row in data %}

                <tr>
                {% for d in row %}
                    <td>{{ d }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
</body>

<script>
function fetchlist() {
    if (document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    else document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';

}   
</script>

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    try:
        form=SearchForm(request.form)
        global d1
        d1 =""
        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
            search = form.search.data
            a = search.split(" ",1)
            firstname, lastname = (a[0], a[1])
            c,conn = connection()
            qry = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM posts WHERE FirstName LIKE (%s) AND LastName like (%s)"
            c.execute(qry, ((thwart(firstname)), (thwart(lastname))))
            d1 = c.fetchall() 
            c.close()
            conn.close()
        else: print('error')
        return render_template("index.html", data=d1, form = form)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some work left to do yourself: keep removing code until you have a true [mcve]. For instance, there is zero reason to keep the dynamic aspect of your query while testing: ignore the form data entirely, and just fire off a query you know runs fast. And if you're debugging, that template doesn't need anything except a form with action="POST" and a submit button, without _any_ fields, and your body doesn't need anything except a one-liner that renders a single row (not even all rows, you're testing, not iterating on a design).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've done that. It only breaks when I execute the JS and change the style tag of display to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know the problem is caused by your JS. This is because the JS is waiting for the search button to be clicked before it changes the style of the list to `inline`.

This all seems fine, but the problem comes in the fact that the JS is executed when the button is clicked. But then the request is posted to the server and a new page is sent to the browser with the search results. However, this new page the search button has never been clicked.

You can fix writing the method to display the results into your template. For instance you could wrap the table in an `if` statement like this...

```
{% if data|length %}
    <div  style="text-align:center;">   
        <table id="list" style="display:none;" class = "table table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Rating</th>
                <th scope="col">Review</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {% for row in data %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for d in row %}
                            <td>{{ d }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The `|length` filter makes sure `data` is not an empty string. Otherwise I believe it may always be true. You could try `{% if data %}` to double check. It may work.

There are a lot more options....

- You could wrap you `<script>` in the `if` statement. You should modify it a little. So it does not wait of the search button to be clicked.
- You could wrap the inline style in the `if` statement. Of course you could use CSS classes instead of inline styling. This would be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. Wrapping the table in an if statement works. However, the search button is only clickable once. So for example if i search  "Ray R", I cannot search for "Ray Ray" until I refresh the page. I'm sure this is the JS doing, is there something specific I can read up on JS to understand?

Comment: I would try dropping the JS completely and removing the `onclick` from you button. It is no longer doing anything.

Comment: That doesn't work, by removing the onclick js and return false it reloads the page. But more importantly it does not generate the table.

I just noticed as well, the list/table is only fetched on the second click of the search button

Comment: I don't think the issues are dealing with are caused by the code you have posted. But I can say that your code needs help. `method=post` should be `method="post"` I suspect there are also other issues.